# Map key during iteration is String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to iterate the map with foreach but my key it´s just a string "[object Object]" instead of the element that I set. what I´m missing here guys.

```
    var elementEvents = [];
    var currentElement = $(this);//(div)
    loadClickElementEvents(currentElement, elementEvents);
    elementEventsMap[currentElement] = elementEvents;
```

When I iterate

```
    $.each(elementEventsMap, function (currentElement, elementEvents) {
    //currentElement it´s not the div element but String "[object Object]"
    /*jslint plusplus: true */
    for (i = elementEvents.length; i > 0; i--) {
        debugger;
        event = elementEvents.pop();
        console.log("binding event index " + i + " for  type " + event.type);
        currentElement.bind(event.type, event);
    }
});
```

Shall I use for what I´m trying to achieve jquery.data()???
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Regards.

Comment: You should get the div's id or somthing else that can be represent as string to set the key, `Object` keys accept string( or Symbol in ES6), so it'll call `toString` on `$(div)`, then it becomes what you see.

Comment: bummer!, what about if my element does not need a key :(

Comment: Can their text distinguish each other?

Comment: `var elements = []; elements.push({ "element": $(this), "events": elementEvents }); $.each(elements, ...)`

Comment: @Andreas Can you post your comment as an answer, I think I'm not appropriate to post it, it's your idea that solves the question. I'd delete my post and look forward to upvote yours.